# Bootstrap Email Sender via PHP

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap to have a modal pop up and lets the user enter their email and message. I already have the modal working and displaying the 2 fields. When the user clicks send I want the content of both fields to be passed to a php file on my server.

My modal code:

```
      <!--Email Modal-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact Me</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body higher">

     <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" Enter your email address..">
    </div>

    <br>

     <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon" >Message:</span>
    <textarea class="form-control"  rows="10"></textarea>

    </div>



  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"        onclick="http://www.example.com/dist/php/SendEmail.php?sender=mysender&body=mybody">Send Email</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The contents of that php file are:

```
<?php
$recipient = $_POST["myemail@email.com"];
$sender = $_POST["sender"];
$body =  $_POST["body"];
$headers = 'From: sample@sample.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: sample@sample.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$sendMail = mail($recipient, $sender, $body, $headers);

if( $sendMail == true )  
{
  echo "Message sent successfully...";
}
else
{
  echo "Message could not be sent...";
}

?>
```

I feel the error might lie in the on click of the send button, or am I not passing in the values to the php file right?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the data like this:

```
http://www.example.com/dist/php/SendEmail.php?sender=mysender&body=mybody
```

use `$_GET` not `$_POST`

```
$sender = $_POST["sender"];
```

It also looks like you're trying to submit other data such an email address. You're mixing both `$_POST` and `$_GET`. You should just wrap this in a `form` tag and submit it to your php script.

Edit: after looking again, your javascript is wrong, use this...

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'http://www.example.com/dist/php/SendEmail.php?sender=mysender&body=mybody';" class="btn btn-primary">Send Email</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, still nothing however. Is there a way I can return any errors via the php to a folder somewhere on the server?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you not getting the email? Seeing an error?

Comment: Still not getting any email. I am unsure of how to debug it and I have no leads..